# How to access third party app from my app on iPad?

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios

I want to switch from my iPad application to another (third party) application.
Is it possible with native XCode? Has iOS any restrictions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Apple's documentation on [Communication with Other Applications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html).  You can launch another application through custom URL schemes, presuming the other application is registered to handle the URL scheme.